# Ggplot center color scale at zero in scale_fill_stepsn

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar

Working data

```
m=raster(ncol=10,nrow=10)
m[,]=runif(100, -0.8, 0.5)
tmp=data.table(as.data.frame(m,xy=TRUE))
ggplot()+ geom_tile(data = tmp, aes(x = x, y = y ,fill=layer)) +
scale_fill_stepsn(colors=c('#b2182b','#ef8a62','#fddbc7','#f7f7f7','#d1e5f0','#67a9cf','#2166ac'),n.breaks=10)
```

However this doesn't center at zero as some negative values are blue
[image]

I am trying to plot multiple figures that show data somewhere between -1 and +1, however most of the figures' data are not centered around zero because the positive or negative data have a larger range. In the plot I would like positive values to be shown in blue and positive values in red and to control the binnes to be 0.1 or 0.2 apart.

How do I programmatically force the color scale in `scale_fill_stepsn` to be centered at zero without fiddling all the time with breaks?  I have tried to play with `n.breaks` and tried `scale_fill_steps2` with which I don't have much control on the color scale.

Comment: As your data ranges from -1 to +1 one option would be to fix the limits by adding ´limits=c(-1,1)`.

Comment: @stefan thanks, I have clarified that each figure's data are often not evenly centered around zero. Most of them are as in the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion a symmetric scale centered around zero could be a good solution.

```
library(raster)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(12345)
m <- raster(ncol=10,nrow=10)
m[,] <- runif(100, -0.8, 0.5)
tmp <- data.table(as.data.frame(m,xy=TRUE))
lmt <- ceiling(10*max(abs(range(tmp$layer))))/10

ggplot()+ 
  geom_tile(data = tmp, aes(x = x, y = y ,fill=layer)) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(colors=c('#b2182b','#ef8a62','#fddbc7',
                             '#f7f7f7','#d1e5f0','#67a9cf','#2166ac'),
             n.breaks=10, limits=c(-lmt,lmt), show.limits=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marco, I think this is a really elegant solution so the reader sees a nice symmetric legend. But then I could probably use scale_fill_steps2 with your approach as well.

Comment: @HermanToothrot Yes, in my opinion a symmetric scale is advisable when plotting correlations.  It allows a more correct evaluation of the strength of the associations in the two directions.